# Why has this question converted to Community Wiki?

Tags: support, community-wiki

I've just noticed that [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/35471/47) converted to Community Wiki after 16 answers had been posted.

I thought that the threshold was after the 30th answer had been posted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As detailed in the answer to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74582/59303) on Meta Stack Overflow, the threshold can be set on a site by site basis and is now 15 for Programmers (along with Super User, where the threshold was [originally reduced in an effort to stem the tide of pile-on answers](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/274/reduce-community-wiki-force-threshold-to-15-answers-on-superuser)).

It doesn't affect existing questions, but if a new answer is posted to those they will convert.

Answer (score 4):

As of April 9<sup>th</sup> 2014, [all of the automatic triggers that convert a post to community wiki have been removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228940/213963).

This includes the trigger for the n<sup>th</sup> answer (which was site dependent) and the m<sup>th</sup> edit to a post.

The corresponding blog post announcing these changes is [Putting the Community back in Wiki](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/putting-the-community-back-in-wiki/).